# Can we bind multiple checkBox controls to a single Domino data field?

Tags: xpages

I'm asked to create multiple `<xp:checkbox>` controls all of them need to be bound to the same Domino data field. If this was an ordinary case I would use a `<xp:checkBoxGroup>` control, but here the checkboxes need to be spread all over the page. I.e.: there will be `<xp:panel>` controls between the various `<xp:checkbox>` instances.
So if user selects say the first of three checkboxes the resulting Domino field will contain the value "*false*" if the "*uncheckValue*" property is left empty, since the last checkbox in line obviously overwrites the values of the previous ones. Only if users check the last box the field will contain a suitable value.
In "normal" html code the various checkboxes simply are connected using the "*name*" attribute. But in Xpages that attribute is already used and overwritten by the engine duplicating the dynamic control id.

Q: is there some type of "native" solution apart from "hacking" the checkboxes' onchange events copying the checked values into a hidden field control?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you can go about this.  For me, the easiest is to bind the three checkboxes to three separate fields, then compute the field on the underlying form that needs to contain the appropriate value.

You can compute it a few ways:
-  Turn on compute on save on the document data source
-  Compute it manually in your business logic during the document save

The reason why I prefer this method is to make sure the checkboxes contain the correct value when the document is being opened.

Comment: thanks for your input; so the other option most probably would be to handle this problem client-side? Compute-on-save is one of the features I always try to avoid, but probably this is the only viable solution here. Unless someone else comes up with a different idea.

Comment: No, you don't have to do that.  You can execute some ssjs prior to your save or put the code in the QuerySave of the datasource.  Keep in mind just calling NotesXspDocument.save() will not trigger the QuerySave.  You need to save the document datasource.